# Fallback for unknown properties in gradle with elvis operator

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to get following to work:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion setup?.compileSdk ?: 28
}
```

But this does fail with the following exception if the setup is not defined:

> Could not get unknown property 'setup' for the object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

So I can rewrite it to following, which will work:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion hasProperty('setup') ? setup.compileSdk ?: 28 : 28
}
```

**Problem**

If I use this, I have to define the fallback (SDK version 28) twice, for the case that the setup is not defined as well as for the case that the queried sub-property does not exist.

Any better way to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found out that accessing a property that does not exist does not return null but throws an error...

The best solution I could find is following:

- don't use the elvis operator
- use `hasProperty` and define default values if you can't find a property

**Example**

```
// define default setup if none is provided
if (!hasProperty('setup'))
{
    ext {

        setup = [
                compileSdk: 28,
                enableDataBinding: true,
                minSdk    : 16,
                targetSdk : 28
        ]
    }
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion setup.compileSdk
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion setup.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion setup.targetSdk
    }
}
```